# JQL query to track assigned to task, but not assigned to project

Tags: jira, jql

I'm looking for a way to create a filter (using JQL) to get tasks to which developers are assigned, but they are not assigned to the project in any role.

This causes hiccups in our flow because at times a person gets assigned (not sure why it lets us assign them), but they can not see the issue as they are not assigned to project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this could be done via `JQL`. It should be rather an `SQL`. This should give you some tips: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-assigned-to-project-roles-for-your-project-705954232.html